# WildFly 15: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I have read other questions on the same topic, but those are not my case. I try to deploy an application on WildFly and have this error:

```
2019-11-14 11:06:58,562 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location D:\work\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\standalone\data\content\6d\d62dd454af846488c4814676d305f116c43aa2\content
2019-11-14 11:07:05,707 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "myApp.ear" (runtime-name: "myApp.ear")
2019-11-14 11:07:06,969 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myApp.ear".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myApp.ear".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "myApp.ear"
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:151)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1738)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1700)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1558)
            at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0031: Unable to process modules in application.xml for EAR ["/D:/work/content/myApp.ear"], module file server-${project.version}.war not found
            at org.jboss.as.ee.structure.EarStructureProcessor.deploy(EarStructureProcessor.java:187)
            at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:144)
            ... 8 more
```

Builded myApp.ear contains all needed wars, **BUT /D:/work/content/myApp.ear is wrong path**. As far as I could understand right path must be something like this: **path_to_local_WF_instance/standalone/data/content/...** Other applications deploy on this local WF without any problem. How can I set the right path and what is this problem in general? Thanks.

Comment: Can you open(unzip) the ear archive and check application.xml? Please show its content.

Answer (score 2):

Deployment scanner is looking for a file named "server-${project.version}.war" in your EAR. Propably the version property is not correct resolved in the application.xml file.